# Skrollr relative mode starts off-screen, ends early

Tags: html, skrollr

Every time I use skrollr I seem to run into this issue along the way, and I'm not sure what the problem is. I just want a simple transition, starting when the element just comes into view, and ending when it leaves view. Nothing fancy. No viewport. Not absolute.

I am using the following:

```
<section
  id="lets-talk"
  class="frontpage-section"
  data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% 200px;"
  data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% 0px;"
  data-anchor-target="#lets-talk">
```

Something must be wrong in the code above. The calculations all occur at the wrong place.

*(all 0px-200px mentions below in regard to the background Y position)*

I expect the behavior to be 200px if the element is at the bottom of your screen, outside of your view. When  it is in the center, it should be 100px. When it has finished going off the top of your screen it should be 0px.

But it doesn't work like that at all. When I scroll so that it is along the bottom of my screen, it is at 94.5px, and it stops at 0px when it is in the center of my screen. It animates while off screen, about half the page up it finally reaches 200px (twice the height of the container itself).

Nothing fancy here, the `#lets-talk` element is contained by static/relative elements like a normal page, with no specific height positions or margin/position offsets.

Here is a graphic showing the difference between desired and actual animation area, in case my explanation doesn't help:

[image: expected vs. actual outcome]

---

See the screenshot below, showing the image **which is clearly in the center of the browser**. The background position set (visible in the top right) is `50% 1.821px` instead of being around `50% 100px`.

As you would imagine, scrolling down just a few more pixels ends the transition at `50% 0px`, the element is still clearly on screen. You have to scroll up, hundreds of pixels after the element is off screen, to get to the start of the animation at `50% 200px`.

There are no other elements with the ID "lets-talk" on the page.

Skrollr seems to be in some sort of offset mode, or is being confused by something.

[image: incorrect skrollr positioning]

### Additional Information:

CSS (mostly resets):

```
background: url(images/app-development.jpg) 50% 0px no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
color: #EFF1C2;
position: relative;
width: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
text-align: left;
```

Containers are all position: relative, display: block, with no height/margin/position related info assigned. The element is visible nearly 4500px down the page. The full website is around 5800px tall.

There is a #skrollr-body element wrapping the entire page, with no styles assigned.

No javascript is interfering with this section, or any parent section.

Skrollr version: skrollr 0.6.25 (2014-05-24)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem by defining a clear height to the target element.

Example:

```
.target-elm { min-height: 780px; }
```